# Viewing Media, Images from S3 bucket onto Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3

I've converted my flutter mobile app to a webapp, all packages are compatible. The only thing that's an issue is all the images, media from s3 bucket aren't showing. Also got the following error:

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
Failed to load network image.
Image URL: https://unicohub-backend.s3.amazonaws.com/9e1dec5605a35af66228cf0b63fdc236

Comment: Is that the actual image path in the S3 bucket? I cannot see it

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to see if there's some change needed for web, cause on the webapp no image is showing, and I'm using image.network to called them through image URLs.

Comment: Have you seen it on any other versions of your app? You're saying "for webapp no image is showing" - is it that you can see it on mobile, for example? Also are the images public in the S3 bucket? I thought i'd be able to see the image by just clicking on the link you provided.

Comment: Yeah, so it shows on the mobile app, on both iOS and android. Basically I'm trying out to turn it to a webapp, and the images don't show with the error mentioned. Also I just checked all images are public in s3

Comment: Thanks for the info. I’m just trying to help you get to the bottom of it. Did you try with any other image online that is public and may be able to show? Trying to isolate a configuration issue on the Flutter side of things

Comment: It could also be a CORS issue since you're invoking a web resource from a web app that is not on the same domain. Can you see what you get on the browser when you run the Flutter web app - what kind of error do you get (status code)?

Comment: Ahhh, just saw we need to add CORS configuration over on the s3 tab, should work with this.

Comment: Let me know if that suggestion worked so I can make an answer for it so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick fix:

1. Navigate to the permissions tab inside the bucket you are using to store images and files.
2. Scroll down to the CORS configuration section titled "Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)".
3. Click on the edit button and add this configuration JSON:

   `[{"AllowedHeaders": ["*"], "AllowedMethods": ["GET", "POST"],"AllowedOrigins": ["*"],"ExposeHeaders": [],"MaxAgeSeconds": 3000}]`

NOTE: This configuration will allow any origin to POST and GET files to and from your bucket. You can learn more about configurations [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a line in index.html under root/web folder

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
</script>
```